# spring amqp rabbitmq MessageListener not working

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I am trying to use rabbitmq using spring amqp, below is my configuration.

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    port="${rabbitmq.port}" host="${rabbitmq.host}" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="${rabbitmq.import.queue}" />

<rabbit:template id="importAmqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" queue="${rabbitmq.import.queue}" />

<beans:bean id="importExchangeMessageListener"
    class="com.stockopedia.batch.foundation.ImportMessageListener" />

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="5">
    <rabbit:listener queues="${rabbitmq.import.queue}" ref="importMessageListener" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

This is simple Message Listener class,

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;

public class ImportMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("consumer output: " + message);
    }

}
```

This is producer (which is itemWriter of spring batch),

```
public class ImportItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

    private AmqpTemplate template;

    public AmqpTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(AmqpTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (T item : items) {
            Object reply = template.convertSendAndReceive(item.toString());
            System.out.println("producer output: " + reply);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run my spring batch job, ImportItemWriter.write gets called. But ImportMessageListener.onMessage does not work. It doesnt print the message. I get below output for all items on console

```
producer output: null
producer output: null
producer output: null
producer output: null
producer output: null
producer output: null
producer output: null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your consumer is not sending a result...

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("consumer output: " + message);
}
```

Change it to a simple POJO; the container's `MessageListenerAdapter` will take care of the conversion for you, and send the result.

```
@Override
public String handleMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("consumer output: " + message);
    return "result";
}
```

EDIT:

You also haven't set up any exchange or routing to your queue. If you want to use default exchange/routing, use...

```
convertSendAndReceive("", queueName, item.toString());
```

EDIT2:

Or, set the `routingKey` on the template to the queue name and then you can use the simpler method.

The `...sendAndReceive()` methods are meant for request/reply scenarios so blocking is required. To do it asynchronously, you have to use one of the `...send()` methods, and wire up your own `SimpleListenerContainer` to receive the replies; you will have to do your own correlation. Use

```
public void convertAndSend(Object message, MessagePostProcessor postProcessor)
```

and in your message post processor, set the `replyTo` and `correlationId` headers...

```
message.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo("foo");
message.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId("bar");
```

Or, build the `Message` object yourself (e.g [by using the `MessageBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#message-builder)) and use the `send` method...

```
template.send(MessageBuilder.withBody("foo".getBytes())
            .setReplyTo("bar")
            .setCorrelationId("baz".getBytes())
            .build());
```

Each request needs a unique `correlationId` so you can correlate the response.

Comment: Thanks, I dont want to pass queueName and exchange from every convertSendAndReceive call. How can I configure it in template configuration ? In documentation the configuration is given as above. I want to use default exchange.

Comment: Thanks adding just routing-key same as that of queue name worked !

Comment: Also, one more problem is, it is behaving synchronously, Each message is sent and responded and then next message is sent. I want to queue 5 message which will be processed by 5 handler threads and then next bunch of 5

Comment: I dont want my producer to wait for reply. It should just queue the message and should get to know when it gets reply. @Gary Russell

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, but I am still strugling to make my async use case working. I cant attach my own handler for reply message in <rabbit:reply-listener/> . It is explained more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196106/how-to-send-messages-asynchronously-to-queue-them-up-without-waiting-for-reply-o

Comment: No; don't try to hook into the <reply-listener/>, declare a separate `<rabbit-listener-container/>` and hook it up to your listener.

Comment: It gives exception if we dont mention <reply-listener/> when reply-queues option is set. There is no example anywhere for how to declare it separetely.

Comment: If you are not using `sendAndReceive` you don't need to specify a reply queue on the template - just wire them up as separate components.

Comment: How can I make my producer wait untill I get replies to all messages and once all replies are received producer should return to its caller whether its was successfull or if there was any exception.

Comment: Also, if I use MessageBuilder, previously working messageListener doesnt work. There should be some sample for this use case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240863/execution-of-rabbit-message-listener-failed-and-no-errorhandler-has-been-set-f

Comment: Sorry; you need to add `.setContentType("text/plain")` so the inbound converter knows what to do.