# How to send messages asynchronously to queue them up without waiting for reply of each message in spring amqp using rabbitmq in java?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I am trying to use rabbitmq using spring amqp, below is my configuration.

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    port="${rabbitmq.port}" host="${rabbitmq.host}" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="${rabbitmq.import.queue}" />

<rabbit:template id="importAmqpTemplate"
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" queue="${rabbitmq.import.queue}"  routing-key="${rabbitmq.import.queue}"/>

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="5">
    <rabbit:listener queues="${rabbitmq.import.queue}" ref="importMessageListener"  method="onMessage" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

This is simple Message Listener class,

```
public class ImportMessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("consumer output: " + message);
        return message;
    }

}
```

This is producer (which is itemWriter of spring batch),

```
public class ImportItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

    private AmqpTemplate template;

    public AmqpTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(AmqpTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (T item : items) {
            Object reply = template.convertSendAndReceive(item.toString());
            System.out.println("producer output: " + reply);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run my spring batch job, each message is sent and handled one by one and I am gettig below response

```
consumer output: 1
producer output: 1

consumer output: 2
producer output: 2

consumer output: 3
producer output: 3

consumer output: 4
producer output: 4


consumer output: 5
producer output: 5
```

It shoudl send 5 messages and queue them up and 5 consumer threads (concurrency=5) should handle them concurrently and should respond as soon as it completes

```
So below should be the outout

consumer output: 1
consumer output: 2
consumer output: 3
consumer output: 4
consumer output: 5

producer output: 1
producer output: 2
producer output: 3
producer output: 4
producer output: 5
```

I dont want the producer to wait for the reply of first message to queue the second message.

I tried using convertAndSend which makes it Asynchronous (doesnt wait for reply) but how do I get reply message in my itemWriter like I can get with convertSendAndReceive ?

If I change my template configuration to

```
<rabbit:template id="importAmqpTemplate"
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" queue="${rabbitmq.import.queue}"
        routing-key="${rabbitmq.import.queue}" reply-queue="${rabbitmq.import.reply.queue}">
        <rabbit:reply-listener/>
    </rabbit:template>
```

and if I use template.convertAndSend(item.toString()); then how can I get reply message ?

I cant attach my own message handler to this listener  to get reply message the way we can attach on consumer side. For reply, it takes default RabbitmqTemplate handler.

Answer (score 4):

First of all let me explain what's going on

You use **synchronous** `sendAndReceive` operation. Before your message will be send it is enriched with `TemporaryReplyQueue` and the sender (producer) Thread is blocking to wait the reply from that `replyQueue`. That's why your all messages are processed serially.

To go ahead we need to know the reason to use that operation in the one-way `ItemWriter` producer.

Maybe the `RabbitTemplate#convertAndSend` would be enough for you ?

**UPDATE**

Maybe do you just need [`RabbitTemplate.ReturnCallback`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e401) alongside with `convertAndSend` to determine, if your message was delivered or not?

**UPDATE 2**

Another thought to achieve your requirement to use `TaskExecutor` to send and receive in parallel. With that you don't need to to wait the rely for first message to send the second:

```
final List<Object> replies = new ArrayList<Object>();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (T item : items) {
     executor.execute(new Runnable() {

         public void run() {
            Object reply = template.convertSendAndReceive(item.toString());
            System.out.println("producer output: " + reply);
            replies.add(reply);
         }
     });
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

And after that you can do something with all `replies` for current `items`.

Comment: Right, I tried using convertAndSend, it works Asynchronousl. The reason I was using convertSendAndReceive is I need reply in my itemWriter. How do I get reply by using convertAndSend in my itemWriter like I can get with convertSendAndReceive

Comment: One more question. Do you want to send all messages first and them receive replies for them, but do it only within that `ItemWriter#write`? What the reply mean here? Maybe there is need to have different component (MessageListener) on the matter and let him to receive replies in different process?

Comment: Yeah I want to send all messages first and then get all replies. I need reply to decide whether the processing is successful or not. If there is any exception at consumer, I would like to get exception and throw it in itemWriter so that itemWriter can make job as failed and log exception.

Comment: and also how can we do it in case of different messageListener component ? Same like we do for consumer side ?

Comment: I've modified my answer

Comment: Thanks but I dont just need whether the message is delievered or not, I need to know whether the processing I am going to do in consumer (my message listener) was successful or not, and may be I want to send message back with some text message. How do i access reply message in itemWriter?

Comment: See my update on your other question where you asked the same question in a follow up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188143/spring-amqp-rabbitmq-messagelistener-not-working/23188700#23188700 .Please don't ask the same question in two places; it's a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks, yeah if there is not other solution that can be done with spring-batch step configuration by just adding task-executer (spring batch parallel processing) which runs step parallelly for different items on different threads. But it will open threads on same server, I want to use messaging for that perpose.